# при запуске бота на пайтон выдаёт ошибку что не найден модуль vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
Код ошибки:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Вячеслав\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vk_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vk_api'
```

Выдаёт ошибку при запуске бота, библиотека вк апи установлена

```
Код бота:

import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
def write_message(sender, message):
    authorize_method('messages.send', {'chat_id': sender, 'message': message, "random_id": get_random_id})
token = ""
authorize = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(authorize, group_id=1111)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.message.get('text') !="":
        reseived_message = event.message.get('text')
        sender = event.chat_id
        if reseived_message == "1":
            write_message(sender, "ку")
```

Comment: А в списке установленных библиотек он есть?